# JGit: How to squash commits

Tags: java, git, jgit, squash

Any suggestions on how to use `RebaseCommand`, `MergeCommand` or any other command in JGit to squash commits? I cannot find many examples and the documentation is not very helpful.

**A simple example**

I want to squash the following tree:

```
A-----B------C------D------E------F------G------H
```

Into this one:

```
A----Z-----H
```

Where `Z` is the squashed commit of `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F`, and `G`.

Any suggestions and useful resources are appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In command-line Git, this would be done using `git rebase -i ...` and then selecting "fixup" for commits C, D, E, F and G. With fixup, Z would have the same commit message as B.

In JGit, this can be done using RebaseCommand:

```
InteractiveHandler handler = new InteractiveHandler() {
    public void prepareSteps(List<RebaseTodoLine> steps) {
        // loop through steps and use setAction to change action
    }

    public String modifyCommitMessage(String oldMessage) {
        return oldMessage;
    }
};

Repository repo = FileRepositoryBuilder.create(gitDir);
Git git = Git.wrap(repo);
git.rebase().setUpstream(commitA).runInteractively(handler).call();
```

Comment: Thanks. Although I cannot find many examples using JGit via Google or SO, but I'm finding that Eclipse bug/patch reports are another good source of information: https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/7779/6/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/RebaseCommandTest.java

Comment: Here is another post about how to squash commits that do not include the head commit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029698/git-squashing-consecutive-commits-that-are-not-the-most-recent-commits-and-do

Comment: Regarding missing samples: I try to collect some useful snippets in my jgit-cookbook at https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/