# How can I limit the number of commits for each file version with jGit

Tags: git, jgit

We are using `jgit` to store versions for some internal files and i would like to allow only a limited number of versions per file. Currently I can add an unlimited number of commits per file using:

```
git.add()
        .addFilepattern(fileName + ".yaml")
        .call();
git.commit()
        .setMessage(comment)
        .setAuthor((String)context.get("userName"),(String)context.get("userName")+"@xxx.ch")
        .call();
```

I would like to check if the number of git versions per file is greater of n and in that case `squash` the `n-version` and `n+1 version` or just delete the `n+1 version`. How can I check in jGit if the number of versions for a specific file in the repo is greater of n and squash two versions or the delete the `n+1 version`? Is there maybe a better way to do this?

**UPDATE:**

Say I allow *5 versions* for each file in the git repo and I have the following entries in the `git reflog`:

A-----B------C------D------E------F------G------H------I

The specific file has the following `git log` entires:

B-----C------E------F------G------H

I can envision two options:
One option: "squash" commits G and H to Z.
Second option: "delete" commit H

I am working only in one branch (master) on a local machine.
I reviewed the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945257/jgit-how-to-squash-commits) question but I am still not sure how  can I do this using `jGit.

Comment: That is not something that the Git Version Control can do out of the box, each commit is based on all previous commits, each change to a file on all previous changes, so you would need to use some rebase-like approach to rewrite histoy all the time, likely rather complicated to do...

Comment: Thanks @centic Can I rebase with jGit one or more commits into the same branch? Please see my upddated question above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We decided not to rewrite the history of files in the repo.