# In java JGit, How to remove all commits from remote repository except the most recent one

Tags: java, eclipse, github, jgit

I am using eclipse JGit API on my java project to mange remote GitHub repository and so far I can use JGit to commit local changes to remote. But I have these requirements that I will only need to keep the most recent commit and I want to discard any old commits from the remote repository.

So I am just curious if there is a workaround to fetch all the commits from remote repo and delete them one by one.

I have looked into using 'DeleteBranchCommand' but deleting a branch does not necessarily remove commits since it only deletes the reference to the commits.

So I tried RevWalk command to walk through each commits, but I could not find a command to remove each commit I am parsing, The following code snippets is taken from https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook and it is used to parse each commits but does not provide the method to remove the commit.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     try (Repository repository = CookbookHelper.openJGitCookbookRepository()) {
         Ref head = repository.exactRef("refs/heads/master");

         // a RevWalk allows to walk over commits based on some filtering that is defined
         try (RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repository)) {
             RevCommit commit = walk.parseCommit(head.getObjectId());
             System.out.println("Start-Commit: " + commit);

             System.out.println("Walking all commits starting at HEAD");
             walk.markStart(commit);
             int count = 0;
             for (RevCommit rev : walk) {
                 System.out.println("Commit: " + rev);
                 //here I want to delete rev
                 count++;
             }
             System.out.println(count);

             walk.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not that deep in git (still preferring Subversion …), so please excuse my perhaps silly questions. But does git allow to remove commits at all? In particular previous/older commits? Independent from what JGit allows to do …

Comment: If you delete older commits, you will also lose the changes made by these commits. Do you really want to do that? Otherwise, [if you want to keep the changes, you have to squash old and new commits together](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22945257/6505250).

Comment: @tquadrat Yes, in Git you can rewrite the history which leads to commits with new hashes/IDs. Such changes might not be undoable. To prevent such changes from being made accidentally and pushed to the remote repository, a _force_ push is needed. On remote you can allow who is allowed to do _force_ push and who is not.

Comment: In git, each commit is a delta which makes changes to the previous state. Deleting a commit will delete the delta. Perhaps you want to `squash` multiple commits together into a single commit?

Comment: @howlger yes I know I will loose the changes when deleting old commits and I still wanna do that. I only want to keep changes in the most recent commit only.

Comment: So the most recent commit adds only new files and does not modify or delete files that would be needed to be added in previous commits, right? You would need to create an empty branch without a parent and then cherry-pick the most recent commit. You cannot delete the parents of a commit without deleting the commit itself (this is conceptually not possible in Git). You have to recreate the commit without its parents first.

Comment: You should push back on those requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was init a new git repo folder, add required files in this folder force push to main branch , and this only keeps the recent pushes only. after ward remove the repo folder and do the same every time.

```
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(repoDir+"/new"));
Git git = Git.init().setDirectory(new File(repoDir+"/new")).setInitialBranch("main").call();

git.add().addFilepattern(".").call();
            
RemoteAddCommand remoteAddCommand = git.remoteAdd();
remoteAddCommand.setName("origin");
remoteAddCommand.setUri(new URIish(repoUrl));
remoteAddCommand.call();

git.commit().setMessage("product list "+new Date()).call();

PushCommand pushCommand = git.push();
pushCommand.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
pushCommand.setForce(true);
pushCommand.call();
```